# How to create a Python treeview with tags and get items coordinates later with QTreeWidget => PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, treeview, qtreewidget

I am pretty new in python (and this is my first post here). so Hello everyone!

I developed a `Treeview` widget using `Tkinter`. I used the next code sentence to create the `Treeview` items and subitems with `Tkinter`:

```py
Treeview.insert("", END, text=NAMESTRUCTURE + lst_ws[n_sheet],                    
                iid=lst_ws[n_sheet], tags=("mytag",))


Treeview.insert(profile_split[0], END, text=NAMEPROFILE + profile_split[1],
                    iid=profile, tags=("mytag",))
```

Therefore, every item on `Tkinter` `Treeview` had its only specific "tag" and thanks to this method I was able to get coordinates of the item in the `Treeview`:

```py
 def treeItemSel(self, event):
        # get the tree selected item
        tree_coords = (self.tree_view.winfo_pointerx() - self.tree_view.winfo_rootx(),
                       self.tree_view.winfo_pointery() - self.tree_view.winfo_rooty())
        tree_item = self.tree_view.identify('item', *tree_coords)
```

Currently I am migrating the previous python code because I want to use the QT GUI. But I am wondering how to create a `Treeview` with tags and how to get the coordinates of the `Treeview` items when one of them is selected.

Note: To create a `Treeview` with *PyQt* I used `Qt.QTreeWidgetItem` but it doesn't create a specific tag for every item.

Comment: Welcome @flote, please take next time a bit more time to format your question properly -- the easier it is to follow your question and your code, the more people are willing to invest their time ;)

Comment: Thanks!! I will do it next time ;-)